# How do I number format for a specific excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to number format for a specific excel in `c#`. At the moment it is formatting all cells after exported from UI

```
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
{
    cell.Style.Add("mso-style-parent", "style0");
    cell.Style.Add("mso-number-format", "\\@");
}
```

Comment: What makes an "excel" specific? Do you mean a specific version of Microsoft Excel? If so, can you add the version to your question.

Comment: @John I am getting values from the grid, problem they have different data types so when I export debugging before formattting it showing the digits in scientific mode after added the code above it start showing the digits correctly now i want to cater just for a specific cells if possible using the code above

Comment: Oh, I see. Isn't it a case of using `e.Row.Cells[0]` for the first column, `[1]` for the second, and so on?

Comment: Your comment provides far more info that your question, consider editing your question and improving it.

Comment: @John Will try that now thanks you

Comment: @bradbury9 Noted

Comment: @John Am getting an error ..cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'GridView'

Comment: What is the namespace on `TableCell`?  Also what type of event args is `e`?

Comment: #Hombone The event args of e is  GridViewRowEventArgs e and namespace on TableCell is using System.Web.UI.WebControls;